# Saving Dataframe within Foreachpartition loop to Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for saving the entire Dataframe in foreachpartition loop to Cassandra.

I know I can obtain the Cassandra Connector within foreachpartition and execute the CRUD statements on cassandra by using the below code:

```
val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "IP")
.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "username")
.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "pwd")
val cdbConnector = CassandraConnector(conf)

cdbConnector.withSessionDo(session =>
session.execute(//Insert statement)
)
```

But I am more interested in storing the entire Dataframe in Cassandra table in one go within foreachpartition.

Also, When I am executing the below statement to create dataframe and write the same in Cassandra within foreachpartition, my app is getting hang and all the threads are in waiting state.

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "***", "keyspace" -> "***")).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call using Cassandra API directly, you can give a try and see if it makes any difference

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark-cassandra-connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra-driver-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and you should be able to save data, and you don't need to invoke ForEachPartition explicitly

```
 .saveToCassandra("schema", "tableName")
```

Comment: I was repartitioning the original dataframe based on column name for parallel processing. In foreachpartition, I am manipulating the partition data and storing the data in new dataframe. Now, I want to save the new dataframe in cassandra table withing the foreachpartition loop.

Comment: and when I am saving the new dataframe withing foreachpartition loop, my app is getting hang.

Comment: Just because you have repartitioned, doesn't mean you have to use forEachPartition to save.  Once you repartition, your partitions are preserved, when you call dataFrameFoo.saveToCassandra (..), it would use your partitions and each executor would call the same function on its own and you get the advantage of multiple executors and partitions.

Comment: I can use df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "***", "keyspace" -> "***")).save() function to write the partition data into Cassandra. Now, the problem is when I am using the above line within foreachpartition my app hangs and when I am using it outside the foreachpartition data is getting saved in Cassandra but from driver, meaning all executors are sending back the data to driver before saving the data in Cassandra. This is increasing Network I/O.